# Passing comparison operator to WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server-2005, case, where-clause

I would like to use a parameter which holds comparison operators like `'='`, `'>'`, `'>='` and use it in where clause with "case when then" or if statement like the following:

```
WHERE  
case @Operator
 when '=' then (@Amount is null) or (@Amount = 0 ) or (Amount= @Amount)  
 when '>' then (@Amount is null) or (@Amount = 0 ) or (Amount> @Amount)  
 when '>=' then (@Amount is null) or (@Amount = 0 ) or (Amount>= @Amount)      
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would do the trick:

```
WHERE 
  @Amount IS NULL
  OR @Amount = 0
  OR Amount =  CASE @Operator WHEN '='  THEN @Amount END
  OR Amount >  CASE @Operator WHEN '>'  THEN @Amount END
  OR Amount >= CASE @Operator WHEN '>=' THEN @Amount END;
```

Comment: thanks for that. But I wonder if can add one more case for the operator ['BETWEEN'] [@Amount] and [@Amount2]

Comment: thanks I did it my self WHERE
OR Amount between [@Amount] and CASE [@Operator] WHEN 'Between' THEN [@Amount2] END

Comment: @user1692483 is the Amount column an INT?

Answer (score 0):

```
where isnull(@Amount, 0) = 0
   or ( Amount = @Amount and @Operator = '=')
   or ( Amount > @Amount and @Operator = '>')
   or ( Amount >= @Amount and @Operator = '>=')
```